# How to stop ISDN to connect automatically

Tags: cisco

Below is my BRI and interface configuration

```
interface BRI0
 ip address x.x.x.x xx.xx.xx.xx
 ip pim dense-mode
 encapsulation ppp
 ip igmp join-group 227.0.0.122
 ip igmp join-group 225.0.0.45
 dialer idle-timeout 30
 dialer-group 1
 dialer map ip 10.22.200.145 name xxxxx broadcast yyyyyyyy
 isdn switch-type basic-net3
 isdn point-to-point-setup
 ppp authentication chap


interface FastEthernet0
 ip address 192.168.168.1 255.255.255.0 secondary
 ip address 10.22.203.33 255.255.255.248
 ip accounting output-packets
 ip pim dense-mode
 ip igmp join-group 225.0.0.45
 ip igmp join-group 227.0.0.122
```

The problem is that when the ISDN is disconnected manually with the command

`isdn test disconnect interface bri 0 all`

after some time it will reconnect the ISDN automatically.  I put `dialer idle-timeout 30` so that it will disconnect after 30 idle seconds.

Please let me know what is the issue and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

That command (`isdn test disconnect`) disconnects the ISDN call, but it doesn't bring down the interface, so what you are experiencing would seem pretty normal.

If I understand what you are after, you need to change the redial attempts in the `interface dialer`.

I haven't messed with ISDN in some time now, but look at this command

> dialer redial interval *time* attempts *number* re-enable
>   *disable-time*

Comment: As you see my config I haven't use any command " dialer redial interval time attempts number re-enable disable-time" in my configuration. So without this command how can it will try to reconnect automatically.